# Given $\lambda$ regular cardinal, $\left(\kappa^{<\lambda}\right)^{<\lambda}=\kappa^{<\lambda}$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals

I'm studying forcing from Kunen's *Set Theory* (ed. 1983), and I came across this lemma

> **Lemma 6.10**. Fn$(I,J,\lambda)$ has the $\left(|J|^{<\lambda}\right)^+$-cc.
>
> *proof*. [...] First assume $\lambda$ regular. Then $\left(|J|^{<\lambda}\right)^{<\lambda} = |J|^{<\lambda}$ [...]

In this lemma, we are not assuming GCH and no assumption is made on $|J|$.
I tried to prove the cardinal arithmetic fact that appears in the proof, but I only succeeded in proving it in specific cases, not in generality (i.e. for all regular cardinals $\lambda$).

In fact it is trivial in case $\lambda$ is a successor cardinal, since then we have $|J|^{<\mu^+}=|J|^\mu$. It also follows if we assume that $\lambda$ is limit (hence weakly inaccessible) and $\text{cof}\left(|J|^{<\lambda}\right)\neq \lambda$, since then we'd have that the the $\lambda$-sequence $\left(|J|^\kappa\right)_{\kappa < \lambda}$ cannot be cofinal in $|J|^{<\lambda}$, hence it is eventually constant. But if we were to deal with a weakly inaccessible cardinal $\lambda$ s.t. $\text{cof}\left(|J|^{<\lambda}\right) = \lambda$, then my attempts fail.

For what I have seen afterward the problematic case does not appear since mostly we are dealing with successor cardinals or we are assuming some form of CH. But still, I wonder, how it can be proved in the general case?

Thanks

Comment: Use `\left(\right)` when you have some more complex terms, like fractions, powers, etc., so that all can fit inside the parentheses. (:

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$(k^{&lt;\lambda})^{&lt;\lambda}=k^{&lt;\lambda}$ if $\lambda$ is regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615991/k-lambda-lambda-k-lambda-if-lambda-is-regular)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that since $\lambda$ is regular, for any $\mu<\lambda$, $f\colon\mu\to\lambda$ is bounded.

Now think about $g\in\left(\kappa^{<\lambda}\right)^{<\lambda}$ as some $g\colon\mu\to\kappa^{<\lambda}$. Then there is some $\nu<\lambda$ such that $g\colon\mu\to\kappa^\nu$. So we get the wanted result, since clearly $\left(\kappa^{<\lambda}\right)^\mu=\kappa^{<\lambda}$ for any $\mu<\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you! Why do you say that $(\kappa^{<\lambda})^\mu = \kappa^{<\lambda}$? I would say, in order to finish, that $(\kappa^\nu)^{<\lambda} = \kappa^{<\lambda}$...

Comment: To quote Shelah, "think!"

Comment: Let me give you a hint, $\mu<\lambda$, and $\kappa^{<\lambda}=\sup\{\kappa^\nu\mid\nu<\lambda\}$.

Comment: Ok, so I'd like to say that $(\sup\{\kappa^\nu \mid \nu < \lambda\})^\mu = \sup\{\kappa^{\nu \ \mu} \mid \nu < \lambda\} = \sup\{\kappa^\nu \mid \nu < \lambda\}$, right? So $\sup\{\kappa^\nu \mid \nu < \lambda\}$ should be a continuity point of $\alpha \mapsto \alpha^\mu$. The last question I have posted regards the continuity of such function, and what I got from the responses is that it is not obvious to check whether a certain cardinal is a continuity point or not. Probably I'm missing something trivial..

Comment: Yes, you can assume that $\nu\geq\mu$. What's $\nu\mu$?

Comment: Yes, I got that. My problem is not with cardinal multiplication. My problem is with swapping the cardinal exponentiation with the limit (sup), in other words with bringing $\mu$ inside the sup.

Comment: Yes, but do you see why $\kappa^{<\lambda}=\kappa^\alpha$ for some $\alpha<\lambda$ or that the cofinality of $\kappa^{<\lambda}$ is at least $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes, I see that, I mentioned this fact in the body of the question. So I suppose that what you are saying is that in the first case you have mentioned the swapping is, of course, allowed, and in the second case instead we use the fact that we are exponentiating the cardinal $\kappa^{<\lambda}$ with something that is strictly less than its cofinality, right? But this latter property uses some CH, to my knowledge, and we are not assuming it...

Comment: @Lorenzo: If $\{\kappa^\mu\mid\mu<\lambda\}$ is not eventually constant, then it has to have a subset of size $\lambda$ which is strictly increasing. So the cofinality has to be $\lambda$ in that case.

Comment: Ok, I see that too, I've written it in the body of the question

Comment: The problem with cardinal exponentiation does *not* happen when the cofinalities are small. So either the $\sup$ is literally equal to $\kappa^\mu$, or its cofinality much larger than $\mu$. In either case, we can move on.

Comment: Ok, sorry, just to be clear, the fact that the cofinality of the $\text{sup}$ is (much) larger than its exponent $\mu$ means that we can swap the two, right? Are you sure that this does not use any CH?

Comment: @Lorenzo: Pretty sure. But to quote one of my undergraduate professors, "convince yourself that this is true". (You seem to be doing a pretty good job on being thorough so far, thumbs up from me.)

Comment: Ahaha fair enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I want to add some details to Asaf's aswer and slightly modify its final argument:

Suppose $\lambda$ weakly inacessible and $\text{cof}(k^{<\lambda})=\lambda$ (the other cases are dealt in the body of the question), then, if we  have $g \in \left(k^{<\lambda}\right)^{<\lambda}$ with $g:\mu \longrightarrow k^{<\lambda}$, $g$ must be bounded in $k^{<\lambda}$ (because of its cofinality),
hence $\exists \nu < \lambda$ s.t. $g: \mu \longrightarrow k^\nu$

So we have $$\left(k^{<\lambda}\right)^{<\lambda} = \left|\bigcup_{\mu,\nu<\lambda}\left(\kappa^\nu\right)^\mu\right| = \kappa^{<\lambda} $$